# windows virtualization under linux that supports USB 2.0

Tags: windows, linux, usb, virtualization

I'm using Linux KVM (`virsh`) and it officially supports USB 1.0. Are there other virtualization tools (free) that would allow my Windows VM to run USB 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) supports USB 2.0

Comment: Can you provide a link to back this up?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads shows that the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack is required to support it

Comment: its also in the manual. chapter 3. I'd paste it, but i'm using a crashy browser ;p

Comment: It does, but I had to use Oracle's proprietary version. Then you have to download an extension pack and enable USB 2.0 in the settings. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Vmware [does](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=774):

> VMware Workstation 6, 7, and 8, VMware Player 2, 3, and 4, and VMware
>   ACE 2 include a virtual EHCI controller that allows guests to fully
>   use USB 2.0 devices.